# Stop a stored procedure from further execution once the condition is violated?

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, abort

I have a following stored procedure and i want to abort it once the number of rows in fact table are not similar to the historical data. So i'm trying to do something like, till now it only sends the email to the users that the data is not same but i want to add an another feature, i.e to abort/stop the SP if the rows difference is more than 5%. But it's not working properly. Can anyone explain where i'm making the mistake? Following is the chunk of stored procedure where i'm making modifications:

```
SET XACT_ABORT ON;

Begin Try

    Begin Transaction;

    if (@delta_ok = 0)

        set @email_body = @email_body+char(13)+char(10)+'ETL process has been stopped.'

    Return

    else

        set @email_body = @email_body+char(13)+char(10)+'ETL process is copying the data .'

    Commit Transaction;

    Begin Catch

        Rollback Transaction

    End Catch

End Try
```

So my question is that if put "RETURN" inside the "if" statement would it stop the SP? Once the condition is violated? And pass to "ELSE" if the condition isn't fulfilled?

Comment: When you have an `IF` statement without a `BEGIN..END` block, it will only execute the first statement and then get out of the `IF` statement. Put the `BEGIN..END` block after the `IF` and `ELSE`, so 2 sets of `BEGIN..END` blocks.

Comment: You have a number of issues here. Your catch is nested inside the try which is incorrect. Don't be scared to use some formatting and white space so you can actually read your queries.

Comment: So basically if i understood you guys properly? If i take "Catch" out of Try statetment and put "BEGIN & END". This should solve the problem? @WEI_DBA

Comment: If i put the "Try" above Catch then it should solve the problem right? @SeanLange

Comment: Not exactly. You need to use BEGIN/END appropriately and fix the syntax issues with your try catch blocks.

Comment: I made the changes and have posted it as an answer. Is it correct now? Can you please confirm? @SeanLange

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your syntax is all over the place here. Using some formatting to add clarity will help considerably. Also you have an anti-pattern in your code I call Try/Squelch. You catch an error but then you swallow it and don't tell anybody it happened. When exceptions happen you need to handle them. That means you need to tell the calling program something went wrong, not just silently ingest the details so nobody knows it happened or how to fix it.

```
Begin Try
    Begin Transaction;

    if (@delta_ok = 0)
        begin
            set @email_body = @email_body + char(13) + char(10) + 'ETL process has been stopped.'
            Return
        end
    else
        begin
            set @email_body = @email_body + char(13) + char(10) + 'ETL process is copying the data .'
            Commit Transaction;
        end
End Try

Begin Catch
    Rollback Transaction
    --you really need something here to log/audit and probably tell the calling program something failed.
End Catch
```